# Angular 6 - promise in lifecycle hooks makes other test fail

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a problem with angular test. I dont know if it is a bug or if i am doing something wrong.

I have 2 components. One that uses promises in ngOnInit and one that is completely empty.

The component using promises looks like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User, UserManager} from 'oidc-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test-promise.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-promise.component.css']
})
export class TestPromiseComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly userManager: UserManager;

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<any> {
    return this.getDataStore('', '', '');
  }

  public getDataStore(url: string, key: string, keyType: string): Promise<any> {

    return this.getToken();
  }

  public getToken(): Promise<string> {

    return this.getUser().then(user => {
      return user.access_token;
    });
  }

  public getUser(): Promise<User> {

    return this.userManager.getUser();
  }
}
```

In the import statements, you can see what dependencies I have and that I use an Oidc Client.

My other component looks like this(just empty):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {

}
```

The test spec for both components just follow the standard spec when you create a new component, so like this for the component that uses promises:

```
describe('TestPromiseComponent', () => {
  let component: TestPromiseComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestPromiseComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestPromiseComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents().then();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestPromiseComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

That is my setup. The very strange thing now is that when I run the test then the TestComponent fails - even though it is the TestPromiseComponent that actually fails. See the results here:

[image: TestComponent fails even though TestPromiseComponent is the one failing]

**So now for the big question:** Why does TestComponent fail even though it is actually TestPromiseComponent that fails?

Can anyone explain that to me :)

**Edit 1:**

Here is the test for TestComponent:

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents().then();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**Edit 2:**
I am running these versions of karma and jasmine:

- "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
- "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
- "karma": "~1.7.1",
- "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
- "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
- "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
- "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",

Comment: Can you show you test suite for TestComponent ? Perhaps just both fail and you just see both error ?

Comment: userManager is undefined. Is it an Injectable ? it doesn't seem to be. You should review this.

Comment: @xrobert35, I have updated my question. Also this can be easily reproduced. create an angular app and copy the component code and install oidc, npm i oidc-client :)

Comment: @JEY. Yes you are right it is undefined. But that will only make TestPromiseComponent fail even more - which it doesnt according to the test result. So for the purpose of my question it is okay that it is undefined.

Comment: I think something wrong occured in the beforeEach of the TestComponent Test. And your TestPromiseComponent also fail cause of the error you got in the console since  userManager is never defined

Comment: Since you got async "beforeEach" I don't know how the test server optimize things, perhaps it run suite in parallele that's why it's hard to read what happen. What is the jasmine version ?

Comment: Yes i know that - I want to make TestPromiseComponent fail to show that the test actually succeeds but then another test fails because of this. If i only run the test for TestComponent then it succeeds so there is nothing wrong with that one :). The point is TestComponent has no errors but fails due to another test - and that should not be possible.

Comment: @xrobert35, I have updated my question with jasmine version

Comment: You mean that everyhing run fine if you remove the error from TestPromiseComponent ?

Comment: @xrobert35, yes. if i only run the test for TestPromiseComponent, then it succeeds. If i only run the test for TestComponent then it succeeds. If i comment out this line 'return this.getDataStore('', '', '');' from TestPromiseComponent then both succeeds. But running both of them using the call to 'return this.getDataStore('', '', '');' in ngOnInit then only TestComponent fails - even though that component has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: You can try to recreate it following the steps i provided in the comment - i seriously dont understand it. It must be a bug or i am using promises wrong.

Comment: **if i only run the test for TestPromiseComponent, then it succeeds** :  even with the  method  this.getDataStore()  ??

Comment: Can you try to only have one beforeEach per describe ?  using the "then( () =>  {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
}

Comment: @xrobert35, Yes if I only run TestPromiseComponent using the method this.getDataStore() then it succeeds. But it actually starts failling when I only have one beforeEach - but still makes TestComponent fail too.

Comment: @xrobert35, I have managed to get it to work. You suggested one beforeEach - which i implemented. At the same time I added a done callback function so now the TestComponent does not fail anymore. My conclusion is that it is EXTREMELY easy to get a false positive in your test. This was really a strange problem. But I thank you for the assistance. Feel free to post an answer and I will mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange to have 2 beforeEach (and also one async) I don't know how jasmine will call same ( in parallele ? is the order they are defined ?  Btw you missed the **await** keyword in your async function so you are not returning correctly a promise which will cause **strange behaviour** for the test :)

The beforeEach should be more like :

```
beforeEach(() => {
    return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents().then( () => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  }));
```